# Babel compile Js files into the same path that origin files are relative to workspace?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

The workspace path is like following:

```
workspace/
    folder-1/
       js-1-1.js
       js-1-2.js
       js-1-3.js
    folder-2/
       js-2-1.js
       js-2-2.js
```

I want to compile files like this:

```
workspace/
   folder-1/
      js-1-1.js
      js-1-2.js
      js-1-3.js
   folder-2/
      js-2-1.js
      js-2-2.js
   dist/
      folder-1/
         js-1-1-comp.js
         js-1-2-comp.js
         js-1-3-comp.js
      folder-2/
         js-2-1-comp.js
         js-2-2-comp.js
```

I want the compiled files to be in `dist/` folder and keep the same folder directory in `/dist`.How to get this done?

Comment: babel \*\*/\*\*.js --out-dir dist --ignore dist but I don't know how to add - comp to file names

Comment: @racz_gabor This is exactly what I need. No problem without -comp suffix.I just use it to distinguish compiled files from origin ones.